# Is it possible to send or receive data on traditional request /response basis using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Our requirement is to send or receive data on traditional synchronous request and response basis using Fire base. Rather than  updating all connected clients when ever a piece of data changes at server .  Going through your Docs... Fire base REST is some thing that looks fits our requirement. Please suggest if anyone have tried it or there is any other way to achieve the same using Fire base.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to synchronously load data from the Firebase Database.

While it is common for developers new to Firebase to wish for a synchronous method, it simply doesn't fit with Firebase's data synchronization model.

[Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener)